# What is the name of this Sci-Fi Circular Interface Seen on Computers and Holograms?

Tags: object-identification, computers, design

Many Sci-Fi movies and video games have this circular interface used on touch-screens and interfaces (the [Iron Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-HYS456aZo) movies or the class select screens from [Mass Effect](https://youtu.be/GoOxjgAeYLk?t=76) are two examples).

What is this structure's name?  Who first designed it/where did it come from?  Is there a math or computer science concept behind it that influences its structure, or is it just to "look cool"?

The pictures below are from doing a google image search for "Sci-Fi Circular Interface"

I consider this more of a "history and background of a sci-fi trope" sort-of question, more than a design and illustration question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What movies, specifically? Where are the pictures from?

Comment: Hmm...  WWPTS?  What would Prof Tufte say?  :)

Comment: Radial interface on a linear display has a low data-ink ratio :)

Comment: In a head-up display (HUD) such as Iron Man's helmet, I'd say *reticle* or *graticule*, but that doesn't seem to cover touchscreen function.

Comment: The [HUD in Iron Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Nz4c0DqW7k) doesn't seem in the slightest bit similar to the choosing screen in Mass Effect 3.

Comment: I've voted too broad. This boils down to "who invented CGI circles", to which the answer is, probably IBM

Comment: I don't see how this question can be on topic as you appear to be asking for where did it come from in the real world. On top of that if you're asking across the SFF genres as a whole this is to broad unless restricted to a specific work. And then you have at least 3 questions which again would make it too broad...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot — "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" is on-topic, according to the [Help Center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Gaultheria This isn't behind the scenes and barely fandom information though. In fact it's asking for its real name in the real world and who came up with it in the real world which would mean it isn't fandom information but more like history of a UI design.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot — How does the history of a sci-fi trope not qualify as behind-the-scenes?

Comment: @Gaultheria Because it isn't asking about the history of the trope but of the design in general... at least that's how it's worded.

Comment: I think this is on topic, because the original poster has only observed these circles in SF and doesn't know whether it exists in the real world.

Answer (score 9):

These appear to be very large and detailed forms of what is normally known (when it appears on a real-world computer screen) as a "[ring menu](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RingMenu)."  The term "pie menu" is also attested, but it seems to be much less common.

I am unsure whether the earliest depictions of ring menus are from science fiction or real-world computing.  Real-world ring menus were probably made famous by the 1993 video game "[Secret of Mana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_of_Mana)."  However, they show up plenty of other places too.  [Here is a Mac app](http://ring-menu.com/) that converts the bottom tool bar into a ring menu.

Comment: There's also the [Microsoft Dial](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/surface-dial/925r551sktgn?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab), which places a circular menu on any compatible apps on Microsoft Surface products.

Comment: I've also often heard this referred to as a "radial menu". (In my personal experience, I've heard "radial menu" more often than "ring menu" or "pie menu".)